# Chrome cannot apply filter:hue-rotate() and transform:rotate() at the same time in an animation

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit

I'm trying to apply both `-webkit-filter:hue-rotate()` and a `-webkit-transform:rotate()` inside animation keyframes.  Unfortunately, not even Chrome Canary renders as it should.

I have created a JSFiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/3QGWY/)**.

If you try removing the `-webkit-transform` lines in both keyframes, the colour rotation works, and vice-versa.  But never both at the same time.

Is there a way to make this work at present time, or am I out of luck?

Comment: Looks like something worth reporting: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en-GB

Comment: or report here if you want to track the progress: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/entry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took a stab in the dark and created two key-frame animations and then declared both for the element, which is working in Chrome 28: http://jsfiddle.net/3QGWY/1/

```
#subject {
  ...

  -webkit-animation:5s multi_rotate1 linear infinite,5s multi_rotate2 linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes multi_rotate1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-filter:hue-rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-filter:hue-rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes multi_rotate2 {
  0% {

    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Jaxo I haven't played around nearly enough with filters and animations so I'm not sure what's going on here that it didn't work with your original code. Glad to help though :)

Comment: This works perfectly; I just never thought of setting 2 different animations and have them go at the same time.  Normally you can accomplish multiple transformations/changes inside a single keyframe block, but I guess not in this case.  Either way, it works fantastic now, it was for my Codepen at http://codepen.io/JaxoDI/pen/gcAbB