# Why wont Chrome animate a CSS filter?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've stumbled across what may or may not be a bug in Chrome. I have a keyframe animation that animates the css blur of an element from 50px to 0px.

It works fine in Safari, but Chrome doesn't seem to like it at all. Here's what you should see

[image]

And here's what I actually see in Chrome on OS X
[image]

Heres a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fj2Ry/1/) should you want to tweak the code.

You'll need to look at it in Chrome, and if you view it in Safari you'll see what I expected to happen.

I've tried defining backface-visibility triggering hardware acceleration, but neither of those have an effect.

Here's the HTML for posterity in case you're reading this in 2021 and JSFiddle has been taken down by the NSA Robot Overlords.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>

            @-webkit-keyframes TRANSITION-IN {
                0% {
                    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
                    opacity: 0;
                    -webkit-filter: blur(50px);
                }
                100% {
                    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
                    -webkit-filter: blur(0px) !important;
                }   
            }

            h1 {
                width: 500px;
                height: 500px;
                line-height: 500px;
                background: #000;
                color: #fff;
                margin: 40% auto;
                text-align: center;

                -webkit-animation-name: TRANSITION-IN;
                -webkit-animation-duration: 0.25s;
                -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
                /* -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; */
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h1>BOO!</h1>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Why is Chrome not handling css blur the same way Safari does?" Because Chrome is not Safari.

Comment: +1 for mentioning "NSA Robot Overlords"

Comment: WebKit => Chrome == Safari if not Chrome === Safari :D

Comment: @GLES Chrome and Safari don't use the same version of WebKit anymore. Google forked it back in April. http://blog.chromium.org/2013/04/blink-rendering-engine-for-chromium.html

Comment: This appears to be fixed in current versions of Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer in this question: [Chrome cannot apply filter:hue-rotate() and transform...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391928/chrome-cannot-apply-filterhue-rotate-and-transformrotate-at-the-same-time).

The solution is to apply two keyframe animations, one for the scale and opacity, and another for the blur. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ShCug/1/).

```
   @-webkit-keyframes TRANSITION-IN {
        0% {
            -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
            opacity: 0;
        }
        100% {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            margin-top: 0;
        }   
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes BLUR-IN {
        0% {
            -webkit-filter: blur(50px);
        }
        100% {
            -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
        }   
    }
```

Which is applied like this...

```
-webkit-animation-name: TRANSITION-IN, BLUR-IN;
```

I still think this is a bug, but at least there's a workaround.

Answer (score 4):

This works - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fj2Ry/3/)

```
@-webkit-keyframes TRANSITION-IN {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-filter: blur(50px);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        -webkit-filter: blur(0px) !important;
    }   
}

h1 {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    line-height: 500px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 40% auto;
    text-align: center;

    -webkit-animation-name: TRANSITION-IN;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    /*-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;*/
}
```

You just have to remove the `animation-fill-mode` attribute because it serves a different purpose than what you are (or might be) expecting - [animation-fill-mode-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573312/animation-fill-mode-not-working/13573954#13573954).

Comment: Works on Chrome on Linux, too.

Comment: It's not immediately obvious what you changed. Care to explain?

Comment: @BoltClock Thanks for your suggestion! I've made the req'd change :)

Comment: That reminder is not necessary considering he has accepted answers to about a hundred other questions already.

Comment: Cheers for that. It's close, I'm not sure wether we're both seeing the same thing, but by removing the fill-mode, at the end of the animation the element goes back to it's state before the animation was invoked. But that doesn't seem to address Chrome's issues with the animation itself, which is that Chrome doesn't animate the blur filter. So What I see is a blurred box that scales up, then snaps back into it's unblurred state.

Comment: Use `-webkit-animation-direction: normal;` in place of `-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;`.

Comment: That's not addressing the problem that Chrome wont animate the blur. You'll notice that the element retains a blur of 50px for the duration of the animation, and then removes the blur in one step when the animation ends. I've posted an answer below, the problem seems to be that Chrome can't handle animations that have a CSS filter along with other properties.